# Visual Studio Code: Use keyboard to jump to first error from terminal output

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, ide, keyboard-navigation

When compiling code using the *integrated terminal* in VS code (not the "Output" or "Debug Console"), it appears to identify anything as a link that has the format
`<file path>:<line number>:<column>`, e.g. `/home/user/myFile.cpp:30:5`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left click</kbd> then allows following that link to get to the specific line in question. That's very handy, but it requires using the mouse, which I want to avoid.

I essentially always need to scroll to the first error, and click it with my cursor. Is there a way to use the keyboard for this instead?

More detail: What I want is basically to isolate the error, e.g. with `make` and `g++`:

```bash
make &> >(grep -A 1 -m 1 'required from here' | grep 'error' | sed 's/: error:.*//g')
```

and then perform a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left click</kbd> on the output.
If possible, the original output should still be displayed, to actually get the error message. In the above command, using `/dev/tty` is an option, but it makes the colour codes disappear, so it's not ideal.

I am aware that one could jump to the next problem with <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, but that does not apply to the integrated terminal.
Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851469/how-to-jump-to-build-error-in-visual-studio-code) also only mention clicking, or using problem matchers, which again only seem to apply to the Output Window, not the integrated terminal.