# Visual Studio Code: how to jump to the first build error in build terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My question is a duplicate (almost) of [Visual Studio Code: Use keyboard to jump to first error from terminal output](https://superuser.com/questions/1738781/visual-studio-code-use-keyboard-to-jump-to-first-error-from-terminal-output) (which does not have any answer).
This is such a persistent problem: I build, I get few hundreds of errors on few dozens  pages in the terminal window and then I have to spend a minute or two scrolling up to the first one because examining errors starting from the last one is not very productive.
How do other people cope with this problem? May be some sort of scroll lock would have worked?

(Note: I am not asking how to navigate in the Problems window - it only contains stripped down error messages, which are not useful).

For now I have to use something like "make 2>&1 | less", but this is not very convenient.

Comment: Can you be more clear HOW your question differs from the one you've linked? Not having an answer is not a reason to ask a question a second time, and I am struggling to see how yours differs.